# in swift assert(0) Cannot convert value of type Int to expected argument type Bool

Tags: objective-c, swift, assert

I am translating objective -C to swift, but I get error when I write assert(0) in swift, the error message is "in swift assert(0)  Cannot convert value of type Int to expected argument type Bool "

my code in objective -c:

```
switch ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]) {
        case UIApplicationStateActive:
            [statusStr appendString:@"foreground"];
            break;
        case UIApplicationStateInactive:
            [statusStr appendString:@"inactive"];
            break;


        case UIApplicationStateBackground:
            [statusStr appendString:@"background"];
            break;

        default:
            assert(0);
            break;
    }
```

and translate in swift :

```
 switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {

            case .active:
                statusStr += "foreground"
            case .inactive:
                statusStr += "inactive"
            case .background:
                statusStr += "background"
            default:
                assert(0)
                break

            }
```

I don't know 0 mean in swift make it   `assert(true)` or   `assert(false)`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you not understand about the error message, it is as clear as it gets. assert expects a Bool, you give it an Int. That does not work. Do `assert(false)`, whatever that is supposed to do.

Comment: Just try `assert(true)` and `assert(false)` ... which one fires?

Comment: @MartinR `assert(false)` will fire

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: You don't have to tell *me* :) It was suggestion to OP.

Comment: Btw., `fatalError()` might be an even better choice, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149040/ios8-swift-uicollectionreusableview-missing-return-in-a-function.

Comment: Actually the `default` case is not needed at all in Swift because the switch is exhaustive. Don't you get a *will never be executed* warning?

Comment: @MartinR never mind I know you better ;)

Comment: @MartinR, I don't get will never be executed warning? so should I make it false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beacuse OC weak typing language, it can auto translate 0 to false, so in assert, it can be run, but swift is strong typing language, so you should use assert(false) or you should translate it by yourself